# Debian Squeeze 6.0.1 - configuration files missing after ssh installation

Tags: ssh, openssh, debian-squeeze

I had installed **ssh** but something went wrong and I uninstalled it. I removed the SSH configuration files by hand **(I deleted all /etc/ssh folder)**.

After ssh installation (I mean `apt-get install ssh`) I noticed that I have no SSH configuration files.

I tried `apt-get install openssh-server` but i still have no SSH configuration files.

Comment: Thanks for the loads of information. You told us which configuration files you've deleted and whether the machine in question was a server or desktop.

Comment: All configuration files :(. I think it is desktop version but I do not know for sure. It is Debian 6.1.0 Squeeze

Comment: All configuration files? Did you mean you wiped the whole `/etc` directory? Or just `/etc/ssh`? Does `ls -A /etc` and `l -lA /etc/ssh` show any results? Do you mean an "installation **over** SSH" or an "installation **of** SSH" (`openssh-server` or `openssh-client`?)?

Comment: You should add these details to the question by using the "edit" button below the question's tags. I suggest reinstalling both the client and the server just to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get install openssh-server` just installs the `openssh-server` package if it wasn't previously installed. To reinstall it, run:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server
```

The package `ssh` is a meta-package that depends both on `openssh-server` and `openssh-client` packages, so removing it does not remove the two.

Answer (score 1):

if you have removed /etc/ssh altogether, before running 
   sudo apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server
you have to recreate the directory /etc/ssh
and a file sshd_config in it if I am to believe my /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst
where I can read :

```
    #Preserve old sshd_config before generating a new one
    if [ -e /etc/ssh/sshd_config ] ; then 
        mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.dpkg-old
    fi

    cat <<EOF > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

unfortunately, that didn't do the trick for me (my settings were lost during an upgrade)
I have to fix sshd_config, I am blocked with

```
   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to  xxx.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file /home/dan/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
   debug1: identity file /home/dan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
   debug1: identity file /home/dan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
   debug1: identity file /home/dan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6
   debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6 pat OpenSSH*
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6
   debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

I don't have any prompt back 
Lucky me :( 
    http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=613505